# Cannot find symbol on i from for (int i) loop

Tags: java, for-loop, compiler-errors, cannot-find-symbol

I'm trying to get a list of cookies and change their value by concatenating a new String the one it already has. Here is my code:

```
    String color = request.getParameter("color");
    Cookie cookies[] = request.getCookies(); // get client's cookies;
    String cn;
    String cv;

    if ( cookies.length != 0 ) { 
        // get the name of each cookie
        for ( int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++ ) 
            cn = cookies[ i ].getName();
            cv = cookies[ i ].getValue();
            cv = cv.concat(color);
            cookies[i].setValue(cv);
            response.addCookie(cookies[i]);
```

I get an error on `cn = cookies[ i ].getName();` The error is `cannot find symbol` and indicates the `i`. Why is that? Can anyone help?

Comment: i edited the post with the error.

Comment: Pay more love and attention to curly braces. The line indicated by the error is by the way the wrong one. Look closer.

Comment: @BalusC this is almost definitely the issue. Your for loop has no braces, so only `cn = cookies[ i ].getName();` is actually part of the loop.

Comment: but he says the error is on the first line after the loop `i` should be accessible there

Comment: Hmm... Is this all of the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for loop has no braces. This means only the first line below the `for` loop's definition is actually part of the loop. As a result, the subsequent lines reference a variable `i` which does not exist within their scope (as it only exists within the `for` loop's scope.)

For instance, in this example, the first print method will only be called if `someValue == 123.` However, the second print method will **always** be called as it is not within the `if` statement:

```
if(someValue == 123)
    System.out.println("This number equals 123");
    System.out.println("This number is greater than 122");
```

However, in this example, both calls are within the `if` statement, so both of them will **only** be called if `someValue == 123:`

```
if(someValue == 123){
    System.out.println("This number equals 123");
    System.out.println("This number is greater than 122");
}
```

Also, `if(cookies.length != 0)` is unnecessary, as the conditional within the for loop (`i < cookies.length`) will always cover this, as I starts equal to 0.

Try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++){
    cn = cookies[ i ].getName();
    cv = cookies[ i ].getValue();
    cv = cv.concat(color);
    cookies[i].setValue(cv);
    response.addCookie(cookies[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cookie[] cs = request.getCookies();
for(Cookie c: cs) {
    System.out.println(c.getName() + "  " + c.getValue());
    c.setValue(c.getValue() + " added Value");
    response.addCookie(c);
}
```

This might help.

Comment: You forgot to tell why the OP faced the described problem. Now neither the OP nor yourself learnt something.

Answer (score -2):

hey cookies can not be accessed using array index the only way to access to use like this`enter code here

```
 Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

String userId = null;
for(Cookie cookie : cookies)
{
    if("uid".equals(cookie.getName()))
{
        userId = cookie.getValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"cookies can not be accessed using array index"* Nonsense. `cookies` is definitely an array.

Comment: Agreed. There is no reason entries of `cookies` could not be accessed with an index.